# magento variable for product detail view

Tags: magento

is there a variable to check if the product detail view (view.phtml) is used?

Why do I need this?
Price.phtml is used in product overview and product detail view also. I want to add a ifelse function when the price is shown on product detail view cause I want some more information.

Regards
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup this is quite easy to achieve;

```
$pageIdentifier = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
if($pageIdentifier == 'catalog_product_view') { 
    // Do something on product view page only
    echo 'This is a product view page';
}
```